# The HTML checkbox input text - what is it useful for?

Tags: html, checkbox

Here is a simple HTML checkbox input element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">I am a checkbox</input>
```

But clicking the text does not check the checkbox, which is solved using the label element instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1"/><label for="c1">I am a checkbox</label>
```

So my question is what is the checkbox text useful for at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the checkbox text useful for at all?

Nothing. The HTML is invalid. The end tag for `<input>` is forbidden. The `input` element is defined as being EMPTY and cannot have any child nodes.

Comment: [HTML Spec (4.01)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) for reference.

Comment: Oops, Stupid me, stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example isn't valid HTML. The `<input>` tag is self-closing, i.e. `<input />` and `<input>` are fine, but `<input></input>` isn't.

You can check this by pasting the following code into [the HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">I am a checkbox</input>
</body>

</html>
```